# Stark Rcpp performance difference within precompiled R package and sourced locally with cppFunction()

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm noticing a huge difference between `Rcpp`'s performance within a precompiled `R` package and when sourced locally using an on-the-fly `cppFunction(<source code>)`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example. Before running roxygen, the package directory structure looks like:

[image]

where the files look as follows:

`DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: bare
Type: Package
Title: Bare Example
Date: 2023-06-29
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: c(
    person("Adam", "Kapelner", email = "kapelner@qc.cuny.edu", role = c("aut", "cre"), comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0001-5985-6792"))
  )
License: GPL-3
Description: Provides a bare example of performance issues described in the stackoverflow question
Encoding: UTF-8
Depends: R (>= 4.0.0)
Imports: Rcpp, RcppEigen, checkmate, stats
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppEigen
```

`code.R`

```
#' A faster-than-base determinant function
#' 
#' Via the eigen package
#' 
#' @param X                 A numeric matrix of size p x p
#' @param num_cores         The number of cores to use
#' 
#' @return                  The determinant as a scalar numeric value
#' 
#' @export
eigen_det = function(X, num_cores = 1){
    eigen_det_cpp(X, num_cores) 
}
```

`routine.cpp`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double eigen_det_cpp(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X, int n_cores) {
  Eigen::setNbThreads(n_cores);
  return X.determinant();
}
```

After I run `roxygenise` the directory structure looks like the following:

[image]

Where the new, autogenerated files look like:

`NAMESPACE`

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(eigen_det)

useDynLib("bare", .registration=TRUE)
```

where I added the `useDynLib` line by hand.

`RcppExports.R`

```
# Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
# Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

eigen_det_cpp <- function(X, n_cores) {
    .Call(`_bare_eigen_det_cpp`, X, n_cores)
}
```

`RcppExports.cpp`

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

#ifdef RCPP_USE_GLOBAL_ROSTREAM
Rcpp::Rostream<true>&  Rcpp::Rcout = Rcpp::Rcpp_cout_get();
Rcpp::Rostream<false>& Rcpp::Rcerr = Rcpp::Rcpp_cerr_get();
#endif

// eigen_det_cpp
double eigen_det_cpp(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X, int n_cores);
RcppExport SEXP _bare_eigen_det_cpp(SEXP XSEXP, SEXP n_coresSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> >::type X(XSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type n_cores(n_coresSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(eigen_det_cpp(X, n_cores));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_bare_eigen_det_cpp", (DL_FUNC) &_bare_eigen_det_cpp, 2},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_bare(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

Now I run `R CMD INSTALL` and use the following code to test performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(bare)

p = 100
M = matrix(rnorm(p^2), nrow = p)

Rcpp::cppFunction(depends = "RcppEigen", '                  
    double eigen_det_cpp_on_the_fly(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X, int n_cores) {
        Eigen::setNbThreads(n_cores);
        return X.determinant();
    }
')

microbenchmark(
  within_package =  eigen_det(M, 1),
  on_the_fly =      eigen_det_cpp_on_the_fly(M, 1),
  times = 10
)
```

which results in:

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr    min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
 within_package 3210.1 3218.7 3318.54 3268.5 3323.7 3712.0    10
     on_the_fly   98.0  102.1  200.30  102.7  106.3 1039.4    10
```

which means there is some overhead being added to the package Rcpp routine that does not get added if you on-the-fly compile the code via `cppFunction`.

Some setting info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2023-06-17 r84564 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bare_0.1              microbenchmark_1.4.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.4.0      RcppEigen_0.3.3.9.3 Matrix_1.5-4.1      tools_4.4.0         Rcpp_1.0.10        
[6] grid_4.4.0          lattice_0.21-8
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make the repository available somewhere?

Comment: Sure. And thanks so much for the help. I imagine it's something wrong with my setup: [public repo](https://github.com/kapelner/bare_example_Rcpp)

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking is an excellent tool. We use to ascertain that things that should work, do work.  And sometimes when they go astray they allow us to wonder why.

Having worked with Rcpp all these years, your initial finding of a '30+'-fold difference was not credible.  Given that you did not provide a downloadable I approximated it as follows:

- your test script, including the `cppFunction`
- a quick package created via `pkgKitten::kitten()` with the argument set for a RcppEigen package; I then copied the function in

Results follow, code further down

##### Results

No real difference as you would expect.

```
> source("question.R")
Unit: microseconds
           expr    min     lq    mean  median     uq     max neval cld
 within_package 89.319 89.837 104.292 90.8560 92.759 224.150    10   a
     on_the_fly 88.853 89.160 164.197 89.5085 90.854 752.128    10   a
>
```

##### Code

Your adapted function

```
p <- 100
M <- matrix(rnorm(p^2), nrow = p)

Rcpp::cppFunction(depends = "RcppEigen", '
    double eigen_det_cpp_cppfunction(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X, int n_cores) {
        Eigen::setNbThreads(n_cores);
        return X.determinant();
    }
')

.libPaths("lib")
library(testPkg)
library(microbenchmark)

res <- microbenchmark(within_package =  eigen_det_cpp(M, 1),
                      on_the_fly =      eigen_det_cpp_cppfunction(M, 1),
                      times = 10)
print(res)
```

I called the package just `testPkg` and installed it in an ad-hoc directory.  None of that matters.  But now that I call *both* the ad-hoc and the package function directly (having renamed the ad-hoc function).  That should avoid confusion about 'who calls whom'.

##### Edit after repo posted

Thanks for linking to the repo.  I made a few small changes:

1. Add infrastructure to the C++ file to a) have the dynamic library loaded, with symbol registration, and to have the function exported.  I.e. I added

   //' @useDynLib bare, .registration=TRUE
   //' @export

and the ran `compileAttributes()` and a fresh roxygen run.

2. Ensure the C++ function is called directly.  Just to be sure, I also added the R wrapper in the benchmark. But why would we call the extra wrapper?  Your 'on the fly variant' does not have that burden.
3. Move the *invariant* thread setter our of the function.  We would call something like this possible once at the beginning.  But not inside the function.
4. For completeness remove the .dll and .o files from your repo.

With that I once again have comparable results (in the median) as you would expect.  In the mean you always get a random tail even once when over the course of the benchmark the garbage collection kicks in.

```
edd@rob:/tmp/rcpp/bare_example_Rcpp(main)$ Rscript testing.R 
Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq      max neval cld
   within_package 1.45189 1.50928 1.56683 1.55025 1.60361  1.74318    10   a
 within_package_R 1.45703 1.48958 1.52239 1.50439 1.56312  1.60523    10   a
       on_the_fly 1.44407 1.44756 2.62651 1.54337 1.64998 12.40928    10   a
edd@rob:/tmp/rcpp/bare_example_Rcpp(main)$
```

Comment: I renamed the on-the-fly function and used `library` to load the packages (just to make sure it wasn't `pacman`'s fault). Same results. I also printed out some session info. Is it possible there is a problem with the new dev version of R? Maybe I'll try on the latest stable.

Comment: No, not that magnitude.  It's likely something more obvious as eg a symbol shadowing another symbol. I suspect you are not measuring what you set out to measure.

Comment: I've made the changes you've suggested (see updated repo) and still see no improvement in the benchmark.

Comment: I then created a virtual linux machine, installed R using apt-get, all the packages, then git cloned the repo, followed your instructions and found the same results. Something is wrong somewhere with the code in my repo?

`> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

and

Comment: Feel free to push the correction to the repo. I think all of this being recorded is good for anyone else who experiences the same problem.

Comment: I upgraded to RBuildTools 4.3 and the problem has gone away on windows. 

I will try to figure it out on the Ubuntu setup.

I find this pretty strange. So I guess there was some bug that is persisting in the combination of Rtools4.2 Rcpp 1.0.10, RcppEigen 0.3.3.9.3 and the current R-devel.

Comment: I installed the latest R-devel from source on my ubuntu and reinstalled everything. Still same problem. Ironically, it only works on Windows?!

Comment: No.  I am on Ubuntu 23.04, using the standard package (that I maintain for Debian, rebuilt in a PPA for the Ubuntu release).  As repeated, I see no performance difference between the three approaches, the differences are essentially noise from running replications.

Comment: Given that there's likely something wrong with my setup(s), I'm going to submit my package to CRAN. Hopefully the issue won't surface in their builds. We will just let this remain a mystery that will become less and less relevant as time goes on. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You could take advantange of services such as r-hub (at https://builder.r-hub.io/) to build under different confihuration.  I think you should dig some more.

Comment: I tried r-hub and there were no issues found. I went ahead and uploaded my package with [github source](https://github.com/kapelner/fastLogisticRegressionWrap) to [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastLogisticRegressionWrap/index.html). Then installed from CRAN on my linux machine and I'm seeing the correct benchmark (see README on github). If you can verify you're seeing the same results as the README, then I think we're good.  CRAN seems to have things working nicely.  I don't have time to dig any deeper. Let this webpage stand as a record that this oddity occurs.

Comment: I am aware you uploaded to CRAN, and I see you already got two reports from Prof Ripley's 'M1mac' setup.  That can happen.   Anyway, congrats you got it onto CRAN, and best of luck to you.